# Radius of convergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> Find the radius of convergence of this series and study what happens in the border. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}$ ($z\in \Bbb{C}$)

I easily found that the radius of convergence is $\rho =1$, therefore the series doesn't converge absolutely for $|z|=\rho=1$ , since $\sum|\frac{z^n}{n}|$ diverges in this case.

Therefore I want to use a convergence criteria, Dedekind or Dirichlet, but my problem is that the partial sums of $z_n =z^n$ with $|z|=1$ are not bounded.

Any hint?

Comment: "the series doesn't converge absolutely" - this depends on the value of $z$. In this case it converges absolutely iff $|z|<1$.

Comment: I had wrong the order of my sentence! thanks!

Comment: Why do you think those partial sums are not bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the partial sums *are* bounded.  Note that for $z$ with $|z| = 1$ and $z \neq 1$,
$$
\left|\sum_{k=0}^n z^n\right| = \left|\frac{1 - z^{n+1}}{1 - z}\right| =
\frac{|1 - z^{n+1}|}{|1 - z|} \leq \frac{2}{|1-z|}
$$
The Dirichlet criterion applies.

Comment: Is the first $\le$ not actually an equal sign? And can you explain how you get the last estimate $\frac{2}{|1-z|}$?

Comment: @philmcole well spotted. And I used the triangle inequality: $|1 - z^{n + 1}| \leq |1| + |-z^{n+1}| = 2$

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the radius of convergence is defined as the *supremum* of convergent series, so there is no need to look on the boundary point itself, if you can get away with a limiting argument. In this case, since it doesn't converge at $z=1$ we know $R\le1$, and conversely we can consider an arbitrary $z$ with $|z|<1$; then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|z|^n}n\le\sum_{n=0}^\infty|z|^n=\frac1{1-|z|}.$$

Comment: "Remember that the radius of convergence is defined as the supremum of convergent series" Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @zhw. The radius of convergence of $\sum_na_nz^n$ is defined as $R=\sup\{z\in\Bbb R\mid\sum_na_nz^n\mbox{ converges}\}$.

Comment: Never seen it defined that way. But it's equivalent to the definition I know.