# Analize the convergence of $\sum z^n/n$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Consider the series of functions $\sum z^n/n$ defined over the complex numbers.

By the Cauchy-Hadamard radius of convergence we have convergence when $|z|<1$, and divergence when $|z|>1$.

Now, what happens when $|z|=1$? For the concrete cases $z=1$ and $z=-1$ I can figure out that it diverges and converges, respectively.

But I am stuck trying to analyze what happens when the imaginary part of $z$ is not zero.

Also, does the series uniformly converge in the open disk of radius 1? My guess is not because of the divergence in $z=1$. Is this argument correct?

Comment: It converges for all other points. I do not recall the argument of hand. It might work with partial summation, not sure.

Comment: In addition to DonAntonios comment, more related problems are [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193542/behavior-of-sum-n-1-infty-n-1zn-on-the-circle-of-convergence?rq=1) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466058/sum-n-1-infty-fracznn).